# dataframe math to calculate profit based on indicator

Tags: r, financial

**Simple explanation:** My Goal is to figure out how to get the profit column shown below. I am trying to calculate the difference in `val` for every pair of changing values (-1 to 1 and 1 to -1).

1. If the starting `indicator` is 1 or -1 store the value.
2. Find the next `indicator` that is opposite (so -1 on row 3). Save this val. Subtract the first value from it (.85.-.84). Store that in the profit column.
3. repeat

Specific to this case

4. Go until find next opposite val (on row 4). Save this value. Subtract values, save in profit column. ()
5. Go until find next opposite val (on row 8). Save this value. Subtract values, save in profit column. 
   **Financial explanation (if it is useful)**
   I am trying to write a function to calculate profit given a column of values and a column of indicators (buy/sell/hold). I know this is implemented in a few of the big packages (quantmod, quantstrat), but I cant seem to find a simple way to do it.

   ```
   df<-
   ```

   data.frame(val=c(.84,.83,.85,.83,.83,.84,.85,.81),indicator=c(1,0,-1,1,0,1,1,-1))

   ```
   df
   val      indicator  profit
   1 0.84         1       NA
   2 0.83         0       NA
   3 0.85        -1       .01  based on: (.85-.84) from 1 one to -1
   4 0.83         1       .02  based on (.85-.83) from -1 to 1
   5 0.83         0       NA 
   6 0.84         1       NA 
   7 0.85         1       NA
   8 0.81        -1       -.02  based on (.81-.83) from last change (row 4) to now
   ```

Notes

- multiple indicators should be ignored (1111) means nothing beyond the first one which should be stored. (line 4 is stored, lines 5,6,7 are not)
- ignore 0, holds do not change profit calculation

I am happy to provide more info if needed.

Comment: My aptitude scores on "business" were incredibly low (2nd percentile) on my college aptitude exams and my math scores were 98th %tile. Does that explain why this makes no sense to me?

Comment: @42- I tried to make it a better R coding problem, does that help? Im happy to clarify any questions. Thanks!

Comment: can you add a few more sample lines which display the system working through your "notes"?

Comment: @Chris- is that sufficient? Im happy to add more if needed, it just takes a while since im doing it by hand

Comment: yup that'll do.i'll give it a shot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was easier for me to work it out in my head after splitting the problem into two parts, which correspond to the two loops shown below. The first part involves flagging the rows where there was a change in the indicator value, while the second part involves subtracting the val's from the relevant rows (i.e., those selected in part 1). FYI, I assume you meant to put -.02 for row 4 in your example? If not, then please clarify which rows get subtracted from which when calculating profit.

```
data.frame(val=c(.84,.83,.85,.83,.83,.84,.85,.81),
           indicator=c(1,0,-1,1,0,1,1,-1)) -> x

x$num <- seq_along(x$val)
x$rollingProf <- NA
# start with indicator = 1

indicator <- 1
value <- .84

for (i in 1:(nrow(x) - 1)) {        
    x[i + 1, "indicator"] -> next_
    if (indicator * -1 == next_) {
        1 -> x[i + 1, "rollingProf"]
        indicator <- next_
    } 
}

x[!is.na(x$rollingProf), c("val", "num")] -> q
for (i in 2:nrow(q)) {
    q[i, "val"] - q[i - 1, "val"] -> q[i, "change"]
}
```

Comment: Where you have q do you mean x?

Comment: The rolling profit seems to be based on the `num` column as opposed to the `val` column.... This question may just be too complicated.... I might break it up into different SO posts

Comment: It's based on the val column. When you run it you can see that the results are correct....If you are having trouble running it, post a full data file on google drive or something and I can run it on the whole thing...FYI, the change in profit is found in the "change" column in the q data frame. The num that is associated to each change is the row number where that change occurred. You can merge the q data frame back to the original df (i.e., "x" in my response) if you want.